# Run program at specific intervals

Tags: windows, operating-system, scheduled-tasks

As the title says i would like to a run a program after every 1hr.
I am using WindowsXp and know about 'at' command , i re-searched about 'at' command to run progams at intervals but it seems that you cannot use 'at' command to so.

Is there any other way through which i can perform my task.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a schedule program of your own?

**Schedule.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{

    while (1)
   {

       system("C:\myProgram.exe');
       sleep(3600) //1 hour

   }

}
```

Now compile and link this into `Schedule.exe` and run it. Use [Dev-Cpp](http://www.bloodshed.net/download.html) as it supports `unistd.h` and other functionalities.